# PHP autodetect translatables / detect piece of code by regex

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, detection

I'm having a multilanguage site which stores translatables within a default.php filled with an array that contains all the keys.

I would prefer to make it automatic.
I already have a (singleton) class that is able to detect all my files based by type. (Controller, action, view, model, etc...)

I would like to detect any piece of code of which the format is like this:

```
$this->translate('[a-zA-Z]');
$view->translate('[a-zA-Z]');
getView()->translate('[a-zA-Z]');
throw new Exception('[a-zA-Z]');
addMessage(array('message' => '[a-zA-Z]');
```

However it must be filtered when it starts with/contains:

```
$this->translate('((0-9)+_)[a-zA-Z]');
$this->translate('[a-zA-Z]' . $* . '[a-zA-Z]'); // Only a variable in the middle must filtered, begin or end is still allowed
```

ofcourse [a-zA-Z] is a regex example.

Like i sais i already have a class that detect certain files. This class also make use of Reflection (or in this case Zend Reflection, as i'm using Zend) However i could not see a way to reflect a function using regex.

The action will be placed within a cronjob and manual called action so it is not a big issue when the used memory is a bit 'too' large.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show example strings you're looking to match

Comment: It's already in there, $this-translate('[a-zA-Z]');
The string will vary but i always trying to keep it like this <headsubject>_<subsubject>_<string_identifier>. For example 'Controller_Default_Welcome'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

```regex
[$]this->translate[(]'((?:[^'\\]|\\.|'')*)'[)];
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- code blocks starting with `$this-translate('` through it's closing `');`
- places the value inside the `'` quotes into capture group 1
- avoids messy edge cases where in the substring may contain what looks like an end `');` string when in reality the characters could be escaped.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/eC5xQ6/

**Sample text**

```
$This->Translate('(?:Droids\');{2}');
$NotTranalate('fdasad');
$this->translate('[a-zA-Z]');
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [17-33] `(?:Droids\');{2}`

MATCH 2
1.  [79-87] `[a-zA-Z]`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [$]                     any character of: '$'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  this->translate           'this->translate'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [(]                      any character of: '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'\\]                   any character except: ''', '\\'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ''                       '\'\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [)]                      any character of: ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                        ';'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: i'm getting the following error `preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 45` while using the following code `preg_match_all("/[$]this->translate[(]'((?:[^'\\]|\\.|'')*)'[)];/mix", $this->content, $matches);`

Edit: Got it working `preg_match_all("/[$]this-translate[(]'((?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.|'')*)'[)]/mix", $this->content, $matches);`
however the preg_match_all doesn't return results in $matches;

Comment: In your first example you have `this->translate` whereas in your second example you have `this-translate`. Is the `>` character important?

Comment: Yes, the missing > was a mistake, the >, or better said ->, is the method call to translate(); thought i fixed it all in my code, had one point remaining, _shame_. Thanks for your help

Comment: is there a way to prevent the capture if the string (the parameter of the translate function) starts with one or more digits followed by _, something like this '1_product_name'? (when the digit is mid in cq not the start, it should still be captured. so only start should be prevented)

Comment: Can you edit your original question to show a full example of what you're expecting to see, and how you'd like it matched?

Comment: done, i added all the cases I've, however you only need to look at the required filters. I already got most of the cases finished. The only issue I currently having is with the filters.